# Result Back from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am sending a broadCast from App A to app B, app B has a `BroadCastReceiver` to handle intent.

Now I do some operation in `onReceive` in App B's `BroadcastReceiver` and then I want to get result back to App A, so that I can have a callback, and continue operations if result is positive.

Below some code.

inside App B:

```
public class TripBackupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        System.out.println("broadcast Received");

        // send result back to Caller Activity
    }
}
```

inside App A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("a_specified_action_string");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Can anybody have any solution for this problem, please guide me with some suggestions. Thanks!!

Comment: Umesh, were you able to get going with this?

Comment: nope, i had to create an Activity in App B, then from App A, i started app B's Activity, using `startActivityForResult`, and resolved my problem

Comment: ah that's a good workaround to the problem. good luck

Answer (score 1):

Why not just (sort of) send an `Intent` from `TripBackupReceiver` that is received by App A?

Something like:

```
public class TripBackupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("broadcast Received");

        // send result back to Caller Activity
        Intent replyIntent = new Intent("a_specified_action_string");
        context.sendBroadcast(replyIntent);         
    }
}
```

You could receive this `Intent` in a `BroadcastReceiver` defines in App A. Or alternatively use the `Context.startActivity(Intent)` method to start an activity in App A.

You may need to implement `onNewIntent()` if this makes a call to an activity that is already running.

---

Please use signed intents for this, in order to prevent users from hacking into your Intent API.

Comment: yes we can, but how i'll get that intent, using `onNewIntent(Intent intent) {` ?

Comment: even how to send intent from TripBackupReceiver ?

Comment: Hello, great answer Only one thing I am missing. You are saying to use signed intents how can this be achieved?

Comment: @libathos You could start by using Google with the words "android signed intents" and go from there. It is not core to this question, which was about communicating between activities.

Comment: As far as I understand, this solution will not make sense if there are multiple applications that are broadcasting an intent for App B's BroadcastReceiver and all of them are expecting back a result.

Comment: This solution was posted as a solution to the question posed by the original poster. It is not intended to solve all possible questions. Other scenarios may have different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar. [This](http://www.truiton.com/2013/04/android-sendorderedbroadcast-example-with-priority/) helped me tremendously.

Basically, instead of a sendBroadcast(Intent) try using a suitable form of sendOrderedBroadcast() which allows setting a BroadcastReceiver to handle results form a Receiver. A simple example:

```
sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle results = getResultExtras(true);

            String trail = results.getString("breadcrumb");
            results.putString("breadcrumb", trail + "->" + "sometext");
            Log.i(TAG, "Final Result Receiver = " + results.getString("breadcrumb", "nil"));
        }
    }, null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
```

Comment: The new receiver you are supplying for callback cause memory leak in my case.