# How to use signed intents in application inter-communication

Tags: android, security, android-security

I have a suite of application that interact with each other. The scenario is that user navigates in one activity, and the at some times he needs to open a certain Activity (not the main), in another application within the suite. I have read online that I can use signed intents in order not to expose my application to attackers.

My question is how can I use signed intents that way?

**EDIT:** The author of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867606/result-back-from-broadcast-receiver/18867928#comment69443524_18867928) answer suggested so.

Comment: I didn't hear about signed intent before, but I can at least filter calling activities using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingPackage()

Comment: http://www.unwesen.de/2011/04/10/android-intent-sender-verification/

Comment: Agreed -- what are "signed intents"?